# C compile error (expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'size_t')

Tags: c, compiler-errors, declaration, size-t

I want to include external library to my project, but I have some problems with it.

My project structure:

```
Project folder/ --- sources/ --- main.c
                             --- libs/  --- Queue.c
                                        --- Sllist.c
                --- headers/ --- main.h
                             --- libs/  --- Queue.h
                                        --- Sllist.h
```

main.c:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "Queue.h"

QUEUE q = {0};

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

main.h:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H__
#define MAIN_H__

#endif
```

Queue.c:

```
#define NDEBUG            // if defined then delete assert checks

#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "Queue.h"

int QueueAdd(QUEUE *Queue,
             int Tag,
             void *Object,
             size_t Size)
{
   // many code
}

// Also many code
```

Queue.h:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H__
#define QUEUE_H__

#include "Sllist.h"

typedef struct
{
#ifndef NDEBUG
  int CheckInit1;
#endif

  SLLIST *HeadPtr;
  SLLIST *TailPtr;
  size_t NumItems;  // line 49

#ifndef NDEBUG
  int CheckInit2;
#endif
} QUEUE;

int QueueAdd(QUEUE *Queue,
             int Tag,
             void *Object,
             size_t Size);  // line 59

// Also many code

#endif
```

Sllist.c:

```
#define NDEBUG            // if defined then delete assert checks

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "Sllist.h"

int SLAdd(SLLIST **Item,
          int Tag,
          void *Object,
          size_t Size)
{
   // many code
}

// Also many code
```

Sllist.h:

```
#ifndef SLLIST_H__
#define SLLIST_H__   

typedef struct SLLIST
{
  int Tag;
  struct SLLIST *Next;
  void *Object;
  size_t Size;   // line 45
} SLLIST;

/* Add new item immediately after current item */
int SLAdd(SLLIST **Item,
          int Tag,
          void *Object,
          size_t Size);  // line 52


// Also many code 

#endif
```

So, as you can see my project is as clean as possible. When I try to compile get the following errors:

```
In file included from headers/libs/Queue.h:34:0,
                 from sources/main.c:7:
headers/libs/Sllist.h:45:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'size_t'
headers/libs/Sllist.h:52:11: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'size_t'
In file included from sources/main.c:7:0:
headers/libs/Queue.h:49:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'size_t'
headers/libs/Queue.h:59:14: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'size_t'
```

I tried include `<stddef.h>` that contains "size_t" definition, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slist.h and queue.h need to include `stddef.h`. Or you could include `stdlib.h` which in turn includes `stddef.h`. As a rule of thumb, try to always include libraries from the h file, not the c file.

Comment: I tried include 'stddef.h' to my C files, but it doesn't work. Now I include 'stddef.h' to 'Sllist.h' file and project compile is fine! But file 'Sllist.c' also have 'stdlib.h' included, why it doesn't work in my case?

Comment: @Andrew Because your c file includes your h file, not the other way around. You use `size_t` in the h file, so at the time when the h file is compiled, `size_t` must be declared.

Comment: @Andrew You should always put all `#include` in the the h file anyhow, since the h file is the documentation of your module's interface, that you present to the caller. They might not have access to the c file. Meaning you should also use the h file as documentation of all dependencies that your module has.

Comment: Thank you for help! I suspected this, but still decided to clarify, because given code was taken from the book "C Unleashed" by Richard Heathfield  and  Lawrence Kirby as it is. Perhaps they are also were mistaken :)

Comment: @Andrew Haven't read that book, but certainly they could be wrong, there's countless of crappy C books out there.

Answer (score -1):

In your `main.c` source file you don't include any standard library header file that defines [`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t).

Simply add e.g.

```
#include <stddef.h>
```

at the top of the `main.c` source file, before your current includes.

Comment: That's not a good design. Every code module/ADT needs to be as autonomous as possible. Meaning it should include all resources it needs by itself.